# get multiple table data without using id equal laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my database have two tables. tbl_counter and tbl_about. In this table have many rows. Now I need to fetch those tables all data. not need to match two table id.

like: tbl_counter.id=tbl_about.id

Just need to fetch all data. how can I join these two table?

Here is my code. this code, not working?

```
public function index(){
    $all_about_info=DB::table('tbl_counter')
                ->join('tbl_about')
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                ->get();
    $manage_about=view('pages.home_content')
           ->with('all_about_info', $all_about_info);
    return view('layout')
           ->with('pages.home_content', $manage_about);
}
```

Comment: This is where Laravel really shines with relationships.  Depending on how you've set these up it should be pretty simple - just eager load the 'about' and you can pull it all in one line.  Perhaps if you show your models and how you've set this up, someone can help you a little easier.

Comment: Could just run two queries to return collections and then [merge](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-merge) them? Granted, you'd need to be careful if you have two columns with the same name. Perhaps post your Models, as suggested by @Watercayman